# Why are std::begin and std::end "not memory safe"?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, std

In [this blog post](http://ericniebler.com/2018/12/05/standard-ranges/), Eric Niebler states that:

> What is wrong with std::begin and std::end? Surprise! they are not
>   memory safe. Consider what this code does:
>
> ```
> extern std::vector<int> get_data();
> auto it = std::begin(get_data());
> int i = *it; // BOOM
> ```
>
> std::begin has two overloads for const and non-const lvalues. Trouble
>   is, rvalues bind to const lvalue references, leading to the dangling
>   iterator it above.

I'm having trouble understanding his point and why `it` is a dangling reference.
Could someone explain?

Comment: How is the above code any different from `auto it = get_data().begin();`. That code has the same problem I think, so what point is the author is making?

Comment: @john Eric is saying that `ranges::begin` is better than `std::begin`, he isn't claiming anything about `.begin`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse OK, I was misled by the title of this post, and I couldn't easily find the original quote.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976859/non-pointer-operand-error-when-dereferencing-an-iterator-into-a-temporary-range

Comment: Personally, I would say that's more a combination of "not Machiavelli-safe" or "not derp-safe" and a quirk of rvalue references than "not memory-safe", since it demonstrates that `std::begin()` is exactly as memory-safe as the parameter you pass to it, and not inherently unsafe solely in and of itself.  That's just me, though.

Comment: It doesn't BOOM in my code!!! Clang 9.0.0 on macOS :O

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `get_data` function returns an object. When used the way shown, that object will be a *temporary* object, which will be destructed once the full expression ends. The iterator now references a vector object which no longer exists, and can't be dereferenced or used in any useful way.

Comment: Though this is definitely correct, isn't john's comment to the original post also appropriate? How does the given example show a problem of std::begin and std::end?

Comment: Because `std::begin` _lets_ you make that mistake, but  `std::ranges::begin` will not.

Answer (score 53):

I think Eric's point about `std::begin` is that it silently *accepts* an rvalue container as an argument to begin with. On the face of it, the problem with the code is also exemplified in

```
auto it = get_data().begin();
```

But `std::begin` is a free function template, it can be made to reject rvalues without needing to add the proper reference qualifiers to each container's `begin` members. By "just" forwarding it misses an opportunity to add a layer of memory safety to code.

Ideally, the [overload set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) could have benefited from the addition of

```
template< class C > 
void begin( C&& ) = delete;
```

That one would have caused the code in the blog post to be flat out rejected on the spot.

Comment: Is it possible for us to make a warning of deprecation or usage for that particular template instantiation instead of outright deleting it? Compiler specific extensions allowed.

Comment: @PaulStelian - Sure, I think so. It's just  another overload, so it could be defined however.

Comment: @PaulStelian - Here's how btw, pure C++14. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c99059b5b1a8dca

Comment: I assume you can't just add the specialization on the std::begin thingy right? But yeah, nice.

Comment: @PaulStelian - No, we can't. I intentionally provided an example in another namespace. To add this overload, we'd need to write a proposal, then get it voted int o the standard.

Comment: The thing is, as Alexandrescu points it out with humour in [its 2018 cppcon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PH4WBuE1BHI "CppCon 2018 --- Andrei Alexandrescu, Ph.D, Bucharest, 2018-10-01, Expect the expected") talk, the C++ committee likes to be consistent in its past errors. One might think the reason why `std::begin` accepts _r-values_ is to let `begin(c)` and `c.begin()` be perfectly equivalent. (but yes obviously this overload set would be ideal)

Comment: @YSC `.begin()` could also be made to reject rvalues, couldn't it? `iterator begin() && = delete;`

Comment: The analogous overload for `std::as_const` is defined as `namespace std {template <class T> void as_const(const T &&) = delete;}`.

Answer (score 14):

The temporary vector returned by `get_data` goes out of scope after `std::begin` is done. It is not kept alive, so `it` is an iterator  into a destroyed object.

Answer (score 4):

Is it fair to say this is a memory safety failing of std::begin?
There is no 'safe' way of creating an iterator such that it will be valid to follow the pointer after the container is deleted.

It lacks a check that another method has, but it's not like there is no way to make a ranges derived iterator go pop. You just have to try a bit harder...

Answer (score 1):

Because it allows initialisation from an rvalue, which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the complicated function can be simplified to two short functions, such as:

```
int& foo(int x){
   return x;
}
int generate_a_int(){
   return 42;
}
```

and then invoke it `foo(generate_a_int())`, a temporary value is generated, once out of the function body, the temporary value generated by `generate_a_int()` is destroyed, and then a dangle reference hass happened.

Do you understand now?